# Из чего состоит туристический маршрут

Tags: терминология

В английском языке я бы сказала один тур или маршрут состоит из **Stations**. 
Какое русское слово лучше подходит? Станция звучит как-то нелепо.

Достопримечательность не подходит.

Comment: А как насчёт «точка»?

Comment: Точки больше если имеешь ввиду маршрут на карте. Тогда наверно можно сказать.

Comment: Остановки, обычно.

Comment: Пункт? "Следующим пунктом нашего маршрута является ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если предполагается на "stations" задерживаться - остановки, если нет - разве что корявые "промежуточные пункты".

Comment: Об остановках тоже уже думала.

Comment: @AnastasiaOsintseva если вы о каком-то варианте думали, но испытываете какие-то сомнения, то стоит этот вариант упомянуть в своём вопросе - это поможет другим людям дать более полные ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Просторечное - "заезды". Например, поедем по золотому кольцу, пять заездов сделаем в церкви.

Answer (score 0):

Место, посещение или в комбинации.

**Маршрут включает посещение пяти мест.** 
**Маршрут состоит из посещения пяти мест.**

Тонкости в подобных вариантах есть, но подобрать подходящие по контексту глагол и форму предложения, думаю, всегда можно.

*И еще. Я тут человек новый, может чего-то не понимаю, мне кажется, что этот вопрос надо задавать преимущественно русскоязычным пользователям и отвечать на русском, на английском все тонкости русского не объяснишь, да и зачем?*

http://rus.stackexchange.com